# How to add a class on an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply a `class` on *HTML* tag, if the tag exists.

**I have tried this code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>index</title>

    <style>
        .black
        {
            background:#000;
            color:white;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('textarea').addClass('black');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>


        <textarea>content</textarea>


    </div>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**What I want:** If the *HTML* body contains a textarea tag then the `.black` class will apply it automatically.

Comment: did you tried to drop that code below jquery?

Comment: you load jquery at the END of the document, **AFTER** you've already tried using it. jquery's pretty powerful, but it can't time travel.

Answer (score 5):

Try moving `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` before `<script></script>` containing call to `$(window).load()` for `jQuery()` to be defined when called

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>index</title>
  <style>
    .black {
      background: #000;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('textarea').addClass('black');
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <textarea>content</textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @msz Note, given `html` at Question , requirement could be achieved without `js` by adjusting `css` to `textarea {
      background: #000;
      color: white;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply style to HTML tags create style with Tag names [Link here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

For your case

```
textarea
{
   background:yellow;
   color:red;         
}
```

this shall apply to all the text area tag on the document.
here is a JSFiddle i created from your source

https://jsfiddle.net/sumeetkumar001/sxxkjbh2/

Answer (score -2):

You don't need `$(window).load(function () {});`, simply leave this line:

```
$('textarea').addClass('black');
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bpbmpru0) is demo.

```js
$('textarea').addClass('black');
```

```css
.black {
   background:#000;
   color:white;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <textarea>content</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: $(window).load() is not the problem. As mentioned in the comments in the original question, jQuery is being used before it is loaded. The correct answer is to move the custom code block after the <script> tag that loads jQuery.

Comment: @Ryan try add `$(window).load()` to jQuery, it's not working with this